# Google Place Api in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I implemented a search event to my angular project.It is working but I choose a place (for example:"Esentepe Mahallesi,İstanbul Çevre Yolu, İstanbul, Türkiye") but response is "İstanbul Çevre Yolu, İstanbul, Türkiye".I use formatted_address of  the response.How can i get first address.

My code:

```
<input type="text" gm-places-autocomplete ng-model="autocomplete"></input>
```

Back Side:

```
 $scope.$on('gmPlacesAutocomplete::placeChanged', function(){


        var title=$scope.autocomplete.getPlace().formatted_address; 
 })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take the value of the input element directly if you dont want formatted address.Add an id attribute and then use js or jquery to get value.

html

```
<input type="text" gm-places-autocomplete ng-model="autocomplete" id="placeinput"></input>
```

backside

```
$scope.$on('gmPlacesAutocomplete::placeChanged', function(){


        //var title=$scope.autocomplete.getPlace().formatted_address; 
          var title=document.getElementById("placeinput").value
 })
```

Comment: Thank you very much.I tried to get  with ng-model but it is not working.Your style is working